# The specified type member 'FullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a jQuery DataTable with server-side processing which is giving me this exception error when using `Administrator = a.Administrator.FullName` for my `data`.

> The specified type member 'FullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities

I have the `Administrator` field in my `Department` class, but still getting this error message. Is there a way to fix this error?

Department model

```
public class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public decimal Budget { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
        public int? InstructorID { get; set; }

        public virtual Instructor Administrator { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
```

Instructor class

```
public class Instructor : Person
    {
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Display(Name = "Hire Date")]
        public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
        public virtual OfficeAssignment OfficeAssignment { get; set; }
    }
```

Person Class has the `FullName` field

```
[Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string FullName
        {
            get
            {
                return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName;
            }
        }
```

Department Controller

```
public ActionResult DataHandler([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
        {
            //IQueryable<Department> query = departmentService.GetDepartments();

            IQueryable<Department> query;

            using (SchoolContext db = new SchoolContext())
            {
                query = db.Departments;

                var totalCount = query.Count();

                // Apply filters for searching
                if (requestModel.Search.Value != string.Empty)
                {
                    var value = requestModel.Search.Value.Trim();
                    query = query.Where(p => p.Name.Contains(value)); //||
                    //p.Administrator.FullName.Contains(value));
                }

                var filteredCount = query.Count();

                // Sorting
                var sortedColumns = requestModel.Columns.GetSortedColumns();
                var orderByString = String.Empty;

                foreach (var column in sortedColumns)
                {
                    orderByString += orderByString != String.Empty ? "," : "";
                    orderByString += (column.Data) +
                      (column.SortDirection ==
                      Column.OrderDirection.Ascendant ? " asc" : " desc");
                }

                query = query.OrderBy(orderByString ==
                string.Empty ? "BarCode asc" : orderByString);

                // Paging
                query = query.Skip(requestModel.Start).Take(requestModel.Length);

                var data = query.Select(a => new 
                {
                    Name = a.Name,
                    Budget = a.Budget.ToString(),
                    StartDate = a.StartDate.ToString(),
                    Administrator = a.Administrator.FullName
                }).ToList();

                return Json(new DataTablesResponse
                (requestModel.Draw, data, filteredCount, totalCount),
                            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the `Instructor` class?

Comment: The property `FullName` on the `Instructor` class is probably not mapped to the database.

Comment: @IvanStoev I have posted my `Instructor` and `Person` classes.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently the property `FullName` is not mapped and cannot be translated to SQL, hence cannot be used in LINQ to Entities query. You should embed the expression in the query, e.g. `Where(p => (p.LastName + ", " + p.FirstMidName).Contains(value))`

Comment: Thank you so very much. Now it is displaying the Administrators' names. But when I go to sort them in the dataTable , it gives me this error message **DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
Parameter name: key**. I have my the Administrator in my `data` as `Administrator = a.Administrator.FirstMidName + " " + a.Administrator.LastName`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @IvanStoev mentioned, the `FullName` was not being mapped, so for my `data` I had to use the `FirstName` and `LastName`fields instead.

`Administrator = a.Administrator.FirstMidName + " " + a.Administrator.LastName`